# On displaying QImage, my application window expands

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

On displaying a picture using QImage, my application window expands, and all the QWidgets gets scattered up and down.

I want the Image to Shrink-fit into a specific square or rectangle so that my window widgets stay intact.

```
    #Student Image
    self.StudentImage = QImage()
    self.StudentImage.load("C:\Users\DELL\Pictures\ABC.JPG")
    self.StudentImageLabel = QLabel()
    self.StudentImageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.StudentImage))

    #in the QGridLayout
    self.StudentAdmissionLayout.addWidget(self.StudentImageLabel,0,2,4,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to scaled your image;

```
QLabel.setScaledContents (self, bool)
```

**Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlabel.html#setScaledContents

---

Example;

```
#Student Image
self.StudentImage = QImage()
self.StudentImage.load("C:\Users\DELL\Pictures\ABC.JPG")
self.StudentImageLabel = QLabel()
self.StudentImageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.StudentImage))
self.StudentImageLabel.setScaledContents(True)
#in the QGridLayout
self.StudentAdmissionLayout.addWidget(self.StudentImageLabel,0,2,4,4)
```

---

Regards,